# What topology must $X$ have if every real-valued function defined on $X$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

This is Exercise 8.16 on Armstrong's Basic Topology. My intuition says it has to be the discrete topology where every subset of $X$ is open. Then it suffices to show that every point in $X$ is in fact open, so then the open sets of each $\{x\} \in X$ form a base of $X$. But I'm stuck at how to show that every point in $X$ is in fact open...any help please? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary, and define a function

$$f_x:X\to\Bbb R:y\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }y=x\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Show that if $f_x$ is continuous, then $\{x\}$ must be open in $X$.

Comment: So if $f_x$ is continuous, then $\{x\}$ is open because $\{1\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$? If this the solution, why does $\{1\}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Shiyue: No, $\{1\}$ is *not* open in $\Bbb R$. But $\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$ is open in $\Bbb R$; what is its inverse image under $f_x$?

Comment: Oh! It's the set of points that are equal to $x$; that is $\{x\}$, which is open!

Comment: But how do we know whether $f_x$ is continuous or not? It somehow looks not so continuous....

Comment: @Shiyue: Yes, the set of points $y\in X$ such that $f_x(y)\in\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$ is just $\{x\}$, and since $\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and $f_x$ is continuous, $\{x\}$ must be open in $X$. The function $f_x$ is continuous because we’re assuming that *all* functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ are continuous.

Comment: ah ha! I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Shiyue: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33954/discussion-between-shiyue-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 6):

Consider a set $A$ in $X$ and the characteristic function $\chi_A:X\to\mathbb R$, which is continuous. What does this tell you about the set $A$.

Comment: I guess $A$ is open? But why is this characteristic function necessarily continuous?

Comment: @Shiyue: Because it is a real-valued function on $X.$